# Java generic "Collection have the same erasure" Error

Tags: java

I want to make the GenericCollection generic obviously. I get this error:

```
name clash: add(T) in GCollection and add(java.lang.Object) in 
Collection have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
```

Collection

```
public class Collection {
    public Object get(int i){
        return null;
    }
    public void add(Object o){ }
}
```

GenericCollection

```
public class GenericCollection<T> extends Collection {
    public T get(int i){
        return (T) super.get(i);
    }

    public void add(T o){
        super.add(o);
    }
}
```

Maybe got some ideas?

Comment: Why should a generic collection extend a concrete collection? IMHO this does not make sense...

Comment: This does something functionally identical - you can just declare `Collection<T>` directly.

Comment: This is an excercise. I have to make a Collection generic. Collection<T> doesn't work

Comment: Well, obviously the method `add(Object o)` has the same erasure as `add(T o)` but they are not the same thing, so the conflict with each other.

Comment: Don't name your types the same as well-known types from the Java API, particularly not ones from `java.lang` or `java.util`.

Comment: Why aren't you using the @Override annotation in the code that extends Collection?

Answer (score -1):

I suspect your issue is that the `Collection` that is being extended by `GenericCollection` is the actual Java collection- `java.util.Collection<E>` and as such you're trying to override methods that already exist in the built in Java collection.

As a rule of thumb, don't completely redefine existing Java classes, because it can easily cause this behavior.